# Is the process $Y(w)$ uniformly integrable?

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-integrability

I came across this question online and am not completely sure of my answer.

On the probability space $([0,1),\mathcal{B}([0,1)),\mathbb{P}=\lambda_1)$, define the sequence of random variables $(Y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ as follows for $(\omega \in [0,1) \space \text{and} \space n \ge 1)$

$Y_n(\omega) := \cos n\pi\omega$

Is $Y_n(\omega)$ UI (uniformly integrable)?

As I understand, if $Y_n \xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}^1} Y$ then ($Y_n$) is UI.

As I can understand we should be able to write,  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} (|Y_n - Y|) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} (|Y_n|) =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} (|\cos n\pi\omega|).$$

Now since when $n \to \infty $ the limit should not be defined since it can be anything depending on the value of $\omega$. Thus, I think $Y_n$ is not UI.

Please help me understand if this logic makes sense.

Comment: Hi @vitamin d, separate from the above question, could you share how did you put the $ n \to \infty $ below the limit. I was trying to do that for quite some time. Thanks.

Comment: There are two outputs. **1.** Writing a big expression. Example: `$\lim_{n\to\infty}$`  results in $ \lim_{n\to\infty}$ but with `$$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$` you'll get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$ **2.** If you want to $n\to\infty$ below the limit but embedding it in text, write  `$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$` to get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, if $Y_n\to Y$ in $\mathbb L^1$, then $(Y_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is uniformly integrable. But it does not mean that if there is no random variable $Y$ such that $Y_n\to Y$ in $\mathbb L^1$, then $(Y_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is not uniformly integrable. For example, take $Y_n=(-1)^n$.

The example given in this question is an other example where $(Y_n)$ is uniformly integrable (as $\lvert Y_n(\omega)\rvert\leqslant 1$ for each $\omega$ and $n$) but without convergence in $\mathbb L^1$.